# I want to draw line in between a css grid and make a tic tac toe board

Tags: html, css

I am currently making tic tac toe game and want to draw a grid that looks like [this](https://i0.wp.com/www.thegamegal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ultimate-tic-tac-toe12-01.png?resize=340%2C340&ssl=1)
but do not know how to do so.

```css
.grid-holder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
    column-gap: 5px;
    row-gap: 5px;

}

.grid {
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-holder">
            <div class="grid">1</div>
            <div class="grid">2</div>
            <div class="grid">3</div>
            <div class="grid">4</div>
            <div class="grid">5</div>
            <div class="grid">6</div>
            <div class="grid">7</div>
            <div class="grid">8</div>
            <div class="grid">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one gradient to achieve this. I also made your code easier to adjust. You can easily adjust the gap and the width. and everything else will follow:

```css
.grid-holder {
  --g: 5px; /* the gap */
  width: 300px; /* the size */
  
  display: grid;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin: auto;
  gap: var(--g);
  background:
   conic-gradient(at calc(100% - var(--g)) calc(100% - var(--g)),#000 75%,#0000 0)
   0 0/calc((100% + var(--g))/3) calc((100% + var(--g))/3)
}

.grid {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-holder">
  <div class="grid">1</div>
  <div class="grid">2</div>
  <div class="grid">3</div>
  <div class="grid">4</div>
  <div class="grid">5</div>
  <div class="grid">6</div>
  <div class="grid">7</div>
  <div class="grid">8</div>
  <div class="grid">9</div>
</div>
```